# How to delete all after 5th slash?

Tags: regex, perl, notepad++

need your help. I have txt file with content:

```
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/50577704157376
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/50735464710341
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/51604546650191
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/51760907550833/album/51760907747441
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/51104812826795
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/51512464113845
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/52331994480761
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/56283345518632
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/50763665834200
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/49222266847410
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/44709448384597/album/44709465620565
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/42776675221604
http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/group/50906863239329
```

I need to delete all after 5th slesh. Solution need in perl or regex to notepad++

---

Comment: If the data before the fifth slash is always the same length, as in your example, you might be better off doing a simple substring.

Answer (score 1):

With Notepad++:

```
Find what: ([^/]+//[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*
Replace with: \1
```

Comment: @user1614240: Is the search mode set to "Regular expression"? I've tried it here and it works just fine. Also, make sure you select the entire text.

Comment: @user1614240, Did you use Notepad instead of Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Perl regex: `s{^ ( (?:[^\/]* \/){5} ) .+ }{$1}x`

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s{^http://www\.odnoklassniki\.ru/group/[^/]+\K.*}{}s;
    print;
}
```

Or if you want to be more generic:

```
use URI qw( );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my $url = URI->new($_);

   my $path = $url->path;
   $path =~ s{^/[^/]*/[^/]*\K.*}{}s;
   $url->path($path);

   print "$url\n";
}
```

Comment: Edit plz to upload strings from txt

Comment: I have txt file with this strings and i need to get a new txt with replaced strings where it needs

Answer (score 0):

```
while(<FILE>){
s/([^/]*\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/).*/\1/;
print $_;
}
```